ASP.NET Web Form page redirects back to login after successful authentication on the IIS server
We have an ASP.NET web forms application that uses forms authentication that authenticates and logs in properly while used locally in the Visual Studio.
However, when trying to deploy the site into a Windows 2016 with IIS server, you can no longer login to a site, it would always redirect back to a login page despite the fact that the authentication was successful
I tested the authentication on the server by outputting into a log, and it showed true using this code
            bool val1 = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

In the web config I tried to account for every script like it is suggested in this post
Here is our authentication logic
       bool isCookiePersistent = false;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                    txtUsername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), isCookiePersistent, groups);

        //Encrypt the ticket.
        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

        //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie); 

Here is the authentication section in the web.config
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="15" path="/"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false"/>

Here is the screenshot of the authentication setting in the IIS

Can some one help how to stop the redirection back to a login page?
We use .NET 4.8

Found the solution, I had to remove this line from Web.config
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />


The above then assumes you not using https, and the above then opens that cookie to other sites using that cookie. It is a considered a security risk. So, that setting requires you are using HTTPS as opposed to HTTP. As a result, my debug config does not that have that setting but when I publish to production (which uses https, and during development I use http), then it is recommend that you use that setting. Of course, it ONLY works if you have https enabled for the site. So, by setting requireSSL, you MUST be using https, and that prevents other sites and code from using that cookie.

It is thus considered a security hole, since then the session or logon cookie used can be hijacked. As noted, this suggests your testing and developing without https (which is fine). but for the final production site, it will fail typical security scans, and as noted is considered a attack vector against your site without that setting. So, making such cookies secure and only usable against your site is still a good idea and a good setting to use when https is enabled for your site.

In the web config file have you tried specifying the defaultUrl attribute?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl?view=netframework-4.8.1
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" defaultUrl="index.aspx" timeout="15" path="/"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false"/>


Yeah, I tried it, but the culprit was the  setting, thank you very much for your feedback
